# SASS Compile and Save in Azure Pipeline

Tags: powershell, sass, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

I am running an Azure DevOps pipeline on a project that requires a SASS compile using dart sass. On the Pre-build I am running a powershell script that does the sass compile. This all works great locally. In fact, the powershell script runs just fine even in the pipeline.

Here is the relevant YAML
- task: Npm@1
inputs:
command: 'custom'
customCommand: 'install -g sass'

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: >- 
     /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
     /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
     /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
     /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
     /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"
     /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False
     /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The logs show that the scss is being compiled.

> Compiled Content\themes\mytheme\css_scss\ie8.scss to Content\themes\mytheme\css\ie8.css

The css does not end up in the artifact and subsequently does not get deployed with the site. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you need a solution to this but from my experience, if the file is not in the artifact directory then either a) The file is not part of the csproj file or b) the file is in the csproj but it is configured to not be copied on build.

Comment: You can use the below extension in the pipeline hassle-free
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=beingnin.process-sass-files

Comment: @Beingnin does this extension compile dart sass?

Comment: @dalcam right now the processor used for this extension is node-sass only. However there is a probable chance the syntaxes used in your sass file is also supported in node-sass as well. So please give it a try and see